# How to detect and extract rectangles with Python OpenCV?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to detect three rectangles from the contour. I have already extracted the entire contour from the whole image. I am attaching the image of extracted contour below. I would like to figure out a way to further extract three rectangular kind panels from the whole contour.

Extracted Contour Image:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Here's a simple approach:

- Convert image to grayscale
- Threshold to obtain binary image
- Perform morphological operations to smooth image
- Find contours and extract ROI

---

After converting to grayscale, we threshold to obtain a binary image

[image]

```
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
original = image.copy()

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
```

Next we create a kernel and perform [morphological operations](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) to smooth the image. This step "breaks" the joints connecting the three rectangles by eroding the image

[image]

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (25,25))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=3)
```

From here we find contours and extract the ROI with numpy slicing. The bounding boxes for the desired rectangles are drawn on the original image

[image]

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(opening, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

image_number = 0
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 3)
    ROI = original[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imwrite("ROI_{}.png".format(image_number), ROI)
    image_number += 1
```

Here's each individual saved ROI

[image]

Full code

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
original = image.copy()

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (25,25))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=3)

cnts = cv2.findContours(opening, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

image_number = 0
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 3)
    ROI = original[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imwrite("ROI_{}.png".format(image_number), ROI)
    image_number += 1

cv2.imshow('opening', opening)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a case for [opening](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html) with a kernel sufficiently large to erode the lines in between your rectangles.

Another way would be to do the `erode` multiple times and then call `dilate` the same number of times.

A little suggestion, you might want to apply a thresh-hold on your image, because it looks like you have some noise (especially on the left and top rectangles).